# Adding ApiController to MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When i try to add ApiController to existing MVC project, it gives me the following error:

> Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

I updated and make sure that System.Net.Http referance is exist.

What is the couse?

The only code for this issue is the following and the error syntax i gave above.

```
public class ValuesController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Values()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

}
```

Comment: You are confusing `System.Web.Http` and `System.Net.Http`, at least in the question. It should be `System.Web.Http`. You need to add a reference to the `System.Web.Http` Assembly (in Visual Studio: Solution Explorer -> your project -> References -> Add Reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*System.Web.Http* is different to *System.Net.Http*

- Add the reference to *System.Web.Http* and then
- And then *using System.Web.Http;*